# How to get label value from stripes:options-collection in java script or java

Tags: javascript, jsp, stripes

I am using below code in jsp page. when i submit i want to get value for label also in java code. how to do this?  i am getting null for empName in java.

JSP Code:

```
<stripes:form action="empManager.action?changeManager" method="post" id="empForm"  name="changeManager">
                    <stripes:select class="selectMenu" name="empId"  id="empId">
            <stripes:option value="" selected="-- Emp --">-- Emp --</stripes:option>
            <stripes:options-collection collection="${actionBean.empList}" label="empName" value="empId" />
            </stripes:select>
                    <a href="javascript:changeEmp();" class="button right">Submit</a>
</stripes:form>

function changeStore() {alert(1);
    document.getElementById("empForm").submit();
}
```

Bean Class :

```
@UrlBinding("/empManager.action")
public class EmpActionBean extends BaseCDCActionBean {

private String empId;
    private String empName;

public Resolution changeManager() {
    System.out.println("storeId :"+this.empId);
    System.out.println("storeName :"+this.empName);
    do something.....
    return new ForwardResolution(Pages.empboard.getPageUrl());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code from you to tell exactly what you're doing but I would create an emp object and in it have the id and name fields.  A very simple bean with getters and setters for those 2 fields, and a default no-arg constructor as well as a constructor with id and name.  Then have getters and setters in your action bean for emp (or a Collection of emp).  In your jsp you'd use ${emp.name} and ${emp.id} where you're now using empName and empId.

https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Indexed+Properties

https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Sample+Application

[stripes book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/1934356212/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=all)